# Nexus 6P on 7.1.2 gives "Device supports , but APK only supports $abiFlavorsHere"; what do?

Tags: android, android-studio, nexus-6p

Note that this app uses native code that's arm-specific, so I can't just comment out the abiFilters line like others have suggested. The code worked before the update.

Is the Nexus 6P only on arm64 ABI now? Or is there something broken with the phone, since the string to list the ABI is null in the alert?

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error on a Nexus 5X after upgrading to 8.0. I turned USB debugging off and back on, then revoked and reenabled the authorization for my computer. This fixed it, though I have no idea why.

Comment: Same with pixel2 after updating to 8.1. I had to reauthorize on the phone.

Comment: Same with Nexus 6P after updating to 8.1.0